# Components of the intercept within regression and colon interaction (:)

Tags: r, regression, interaction, intercept

I'm trying to figure out which elements are part of the intercept within a regression model characterized by colon interaction (:).

This is the model:

Y ~ A*B + A:B:C

The independent variables are:

```
 A: numeric
 B: categorical with 2 levels (1B, 2B)
 C: categorical with 4 levels (1C, 2C, 3C, 4C)
```

The summary reports:

```
Intercept
A
2B
A:2B
A:2B:2C
A:2B:3C
A:2B:4C
A:1B:2C
A:1B:3C
A:1B:4C
```

Which elements compose the intercept?
I suppose 1B and 1C. Is it right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should also be a main effect for `A` resulting from `A*B`. Why is the main effect for `C` not included ? It very rarely makes sense to include a variable in an interaction but exclude it's main effect. `Y ~ A*B*C` would make more sense.

Comment: I forgot to write down the main effect for A resulting from A*B, i've just edited the text, sorry. The first reason why i did not include the main effect of C was to let the model run correctly. Tje interaction A*B*C led to convergence and overfitting problems. The second reason was linked to the ecological meaning of the main effect of C:  i do not want to know its main effect but only with the interaction with the other two terms A and B. Can i adfirm that the intercept of the model is composed by the 1B and 1C terms?